# Convert Kivy python app to and apk for Android

Tags: android, python, file, save, buildozer

I'm working in an app that provides you an icalendar file with a schedule of some subjects. I have done the app through kivy in python and it works in Python, but when I tried to pass to an apk with Buildozer module I realized that it didn't work properly. The fact is that when the file with the calendar is created I think that can't be saved in the right way (in pc is saved in the same directory of the app files) and the kivy app crashes when I try to create the file. Does somebody know what is happening to me? The next step is to send the file through email in a email account that you provide to the app in the first Screen, but first of all I want to know if I'm doing the previous steps in the right way. I know the issue is in the creation of the file because when I create the file I can't find it in the mobile phone, and when I run in python console is created. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we go step by step,your first problem is to locate the apk file.That gets created inside bin directory of the app folder if you run this command

```
buildozer android debug
```

you can then copy the apk file in your android phone and manually install it by setting the option to install 3rd party app from settings.
If you want to do it automatically enable the developer mode in your android device or use an emulator and connect the device to your laptop/pc with usb and run following command after setting the log level as 2 from buildozer.spec

```
buildozer -v android debug deply run
```

If you also want to see why it is crashing inside android run following command
and inspect the log.txt file created using following command

```
buildozer -v android debug deply run logcat > log.txt
```

or

```
adb logcat > log.txt
```